# Dynamically add fields to a ModelForm in Django

Tags: django

I have a few models: Product, Review and Comment. A Product has reviews, and a review has comments. I wrote the code as following:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s on %s' % (self.author, self.date)

class Review(models.Model):
    stars = models.FloatField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='upload', null = True, blank = True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='upload', null = True, blank = True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s by %s' % (self.author, self.title)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='upload', null = True, blank = True)
    reviews = models.ManyToManyField(Review)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Similarly, I have ModelForms that are based on the models, as following:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ['author']
        labels = {
            'content': _('Comment:'),
        }

class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ['reviews']

class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        exclude = ['author', 'comments']
```

Until here, everything works great. Now, I would like to be able to dynamically add questions to a product. Therefore, when the admin creates a new product, he will be able to add product-specific questions (e.g. how is the color of the product etc.) to it (how many questions he wants - dynamic). Then, when the user goes to review a product, he will see the product-specific questions that the admin asked and he will be able to answer them.

So, My main issues are:
a. how to dynamically add fields to the database model?
b. how to handle these question inside of a review? There could potentially be several reviews on one product, each by a different person and each should display these product-specific questions.

Thanks!

Comment: What about creating a `Question` model, having `ForeignKey` to a `Product`, and creating a `QuestionAnswer` model, containing reference to the `Question` and the answer, linked to `Review` by a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: @trnsnt Thanks for that! What do you mean by reference to the Question? as in a foreignkey? Can you give some code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a quick exemple of what I have put in comment (done with notepad, maybe there is typo):

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    pass

class Review(models.Model):
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(Comment)

class Product(models.Model):
    reviews = models.ManyToManyField(Review)

class Question(models.Model):.
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 500)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

Comment: OK cool, I'll try that, thanks! And what about dynamically adding questions to a product? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want to say by  dynamically adding questions. With exemple I have posted, you can add as many question you want to a product by doing someting like:
`Question.objects.create(product=your_product, content=content)`

Comment: OK.. And do I need to create a separate ModelForm to the question model?

Comment: Yes, you need it if you want to create a question!